# Wget - Convert links after download

Tags: download, conversion, wget, links

I've downloaded a page with `wget -m` a good while ago. The internal links were not converted correctly so whenever the url includes a `?` (GET parameters), the link is broken.
If I change the `?` in the URL with the `%3F`, the link works. However I obviously can't change all the question marks in the page since some of them are part of external URLs, javascript or other parts of the page.

Which tool can I use to fix these broken links?

The page doesn't exist anymore so I can not re-download it (with different wget options)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to replace all `?` with a certain context, like

```
sed 's/?\([a-z][A-Z]\)/%3F\1/g' a.html > b.html
```

This will process `a.html` (leaving it untouched) and create/overwrite `b.html` with modified HTML text.

The `sed` expression will find `?` followed by a letter (`[a-z][A-Z]`), capture the letter (`\(`..`\)`), and replace it with `%3F` and the captured letter (`\1`).

Depending on your HTML file, you might have to refine the context to get a working result.

Answer (score -1):

You can use --no-cobbler option with -k .

`-nc` will ensure files are not downloaded again.
`-k` will convert links if the file exists on server.

```
wget -rk -nc https://example.com
```

Comment: This doesn't work, wget says `Both --no-clobber and --convert-links were specified, only --convert-links will be used.` Which was added because in wget 1.12 and prior, "-k doesn't convert links correctly for files which already exist." See this bug and the linked SO question. http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?31781